# How do I set up log4j2 in an Alexa skills maven project?

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I'm developing an Alexa skill using Java to handle the intents.

The Java project is a maven project.  One of the dependencies is on Apache's log4j2.

Here's a snapshot of the log file from my last test.  I wish Amazon would allow you to download logs.  Edited: I found a way to copy and paste part of the log.

```
START RequestId: 5077a4b9-f3ad-49f9-9f79-0c78e443bf41 Version: $LATEST
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
END RequestId: 5077a4b9-f3ad-49f9-9f79-0c78e443bf41
REPORT RequestId: 5077a4b9-f3ad-49f9-9f79-0c78e443bf41  Duration: 2117.38 ms    Billed Duration: 2200 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 155 MB Init Duration: 3143.46 ms   
START RequestId: d3bff3f0-a270-4a02-8cbc-a2be3162741f Version: $LATEST
22:37:48.898 [main] ERROR com.ggl.bible.reader.ReadingTypeIntentHandler - Mode value: reading
22:37:48.916 [main] ERROR com.ggl.bible.reader.ReadingTypeIntentHandler - Reading decision value: reading
22:37:48.997 [main] ERROR com.ggl.bible.reader.ReadingTypeIntentHandler - Reading Decision reading not understood
END RequestId: d3bff3f0-a270-4a02-8cbc-a2be3162741f
```

I don't know if the image is clear enough, but the second line tells me that the log4j2 can't find the log4j2 configuration file.

I have a log4j.properties file in src/main/resources.  It's not much, but it's all I need

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
```

As you can see from the image (I hope), lines 6 - 8 at 22:37:48 are logger output.  For now, all of my logger output is written as ERROR.  While this "works", I'd like to be able to distinguish the information from the actual error.

The first two logger lines are information.  The third line is an actual error where Alexa didn't interpret the word as I would have liked.

I'd like to set up a working log4j properties file, and I'd like to know where the properties file is supposed to be placed in a maven project.  Thanks for your help.

As requested in the comments, the Java class with the logger comments is too long to post in its entirety.

Here's the logger definition.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ReadingTypeIntentHandler.class);
```

Here's a few lines of logger methods.

```
    if (modeValue.isPresent()) {
        logger.error("Mode value: " + modeValue.get());
    }

    if (bookValue.isPresent()) {
        logger.error("Book value: " + bookValue.get());
    }

    if (startChapterValue.isPresent()) {
        logger.error("Start chapter value: " + startChapterValue.get());
    }
```

The Java code works.  The messages appear in the log file.

My pom dependency is here.  If there's more than one needed, tell me what else I need.  Maven isn't telling me I'm missing anything.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Edited again:  Adding a pom dependency for log4j-api had no effect.

Adding a log4j2.xml file to src/main/resources got rid of the "No log4j2 configuration file found." message in the log.  This was the practical answer for me.

Here's the log4j2.xml file I used.  I hope this question helps future Alexa skills developers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code about how you log your information?

Comment: Also please show your pom dependencies. There is more than one dependency required for log4j2.

Comment: Moreover, I highly recommend to set your log4j2 to TRACE in the RunConfigs:
`key`:`org.apache.logging.log4j.simpleLog.StatusLogger.Level` `value`:`TRACE`
This will display the process of Log4j2 searching for the properties file.

Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/configuration.html (Scroll down to "Status Messages")